# I want to use camelot for table extraction but its giving error

Tags: python, python-camelot, pdf-extraction

```
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf(r"F:\testing\sbi_9.pdf", pages="all")
```

I have also downloaded GhostScript and still showing an error.

```
DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead.
```

What can I do now?

I also tried it on Google Collab but it's not working.
Can anyone give me the proper steps to extract tables using Camelot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/339) github issue of camelot, a workaround would be to install the missing library:

```
pip install --upgrade PyPDF2==2.12.1
```

However, you might want to upgrade your `camelot` library, because this issue seems to have been fixed [in february this year](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/pull/307)